# how defined time in computer

Tags: computer-science

I know that the computer knows 0 and 1. I know that 1 is True (current on) and 0 is False (current off). but how we say to computer :1 second ?
I actually say that how do we define time for computer and all of other electronic tools?

Comment: Your questions makes very little sense.

Comment: In some Basics TRUE is 0

Comment: "Current on", as vague as that state is at the scale of tens of nm, usually translates to binary 0, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Time is generally stored as a number of units since some fixed date (eg, [number of seconds since January 1<sup>st</sup>, 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).
This number is stored internally in binary.

Answer (score 1):

From [System Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time):

> System time is measured by a system clock, which is typically
>   implemented as a simple count of the number of ticks that have
>   transpired since some arbitrary starting date.

The operating system provides a way for programs to get this information from a hardware unit.